# Conflicts in traits is not working

Tags: php, oop, traits

I wonder why this is not working .. Second line of trait implementation and not showing any error.. when I comment that like it works

```
trait Laptop{
    public function battery_life(){
        echo "Laptop battery life";
    }
}
trait Mobile{
    public function battery_life(){
        echo "Mobile battery life";
    }
}
class A{
    use Laptop,Mobile{
        Laptop::battery_life insteadof Mobile;
        Moblile::battery_life as MobileBatterylife;// This is not working
    }
}
$obj = new A;
$obj->battery_life();
```

Comment: are you setting error display errors option to display your errors?

Answer (score -1):

You have typo in your "Mobile" word:

```
Moblile::battery_life as MobileBatterylife;
```

it should be

```
Mobile::battery_life as MobileBatterylife;
```